# Can't ping host network by name from Docker bridged container

Tags: docker

06.1-ce

I have a container running in bridge newtork

```
"IPAM": {
  "Driver": "default",
  "Options": null,
  "Config": [
    {
      "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
      "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
    }
  ]
}
```

I can access my containers no problem, but I need to connect to a machine on the host network. When I docker exec -ti bash inside the container, I can ping by I.P but not by name. Is that how Docker bridge network works?

**Update**

I can ping by full name. So is there a way to set the search domain for containers?

Answer (score 0):

Ok we can set the DNS settings when using docker run

such as: --dns-search=mydomain.com

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/

Comment: could you please explain more on this, that how were able to ping that docker IP